# Are numbers seen as strings in sql 

Tags: sql-server-2008, nvarchar

This is really simple. Does `SQL SERVER 2008` auto convert values to string for you ?

I tried this `Select * from Staff Where Division = 5`
If I try to insert it, it works too.
If I change 5 for five I get and error though. `Invalid column name five`.

Division is a `NVARCHAR`. Shoudn't the 5 be within single quotes ?

Comment: @Pha....yes it needs to be single quoted. You will get an error if not...Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '(None)' to data type int.

Comment: @MikeTWebb I have it right in front of me. And it workf perfectly. Maybe I should screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQL Server does an implicit conversion of int to nvarchar. It can also implicitly convert nvarchar to int (and other numeric types).

For more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of cases where implicit conversion takes place. For example:

```
EXEC sp_who2 active;
```

Shouldn't you need to delimit `active` as a string? Yes, but the syntax is forgiving.

My suggestion: always delimit data types correctly, and ignore the exceptions. The chances they'll ever get comprehensively fixed are close to nil.

Comment: Thanks a lot I though I was crazy